# find -exec command options with basename

Tags: find, options, basename

I have the following JPEG files :

```
$ ls -l
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 384065 janv. 21 12:10 CamScanner 01-10-2022 14.54.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 200892 janv. 10 14:55 CamScanner 01-10-2022 14.55.jpg
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 283821 janv. 21 12:10 CamScanner 01-10-2022 14.56.jpg
```

I use `$ img2pdf` to transform each image into a PDF file. To do that :

```
$ find . -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec img2pdf "{}" --output $(basename {} .jpg).pdf \;
```

Result :

```
$ ls -l *.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 385060 janv. 21 13:06 CamScanner 01-10-2022 14.54.jpg.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 201887 janv. 21 13:06 CamScanner 01-10-2022 14.55.jpg.pdf
-rw-r--r-- 1 user group 284816 janv. 21 13:06 CamScanner 01-10-2022 14.56.jpg.pdf
```

How can I remove the `.jpg` part of the PDF filenames ? I.e., I want `CamScanner 01-10-2022 14.54.pdf` and not `CamScanner 01-10-2022 14.54.jpg.pdf`.

Used alone, `$ basename filename .extension` prints the filename without the extension, e.g. :

```
$ basename CamScanner\ 01-10-2022\ 14.54.jpg .jpg
CamScanner 01-10-2022 14.54
```

But it seems that syntax doesn't work in my `$ find` command. Any idea why ?

Note : if you replace `$ img2pdf` by `$ echo` it's the same, `$ basename` doesn't get rid of the `.jpg` part :

```
$ find . -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec echo $(basename {} .jpg).pdf \;
./CamScanner 01-10-2022 14.56.jpg.pdf
./CamScanner 01-10-2022 14.55.jpg.pdf
./CamScanner 01-10-2022 14.54.jpg.pdf
```

Comment: Crystal ball guess: `$()` is shell expansion, that's done before find even gets called. At that point, basename tries to work on the literal `{}`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue with your `find` command is that the command substitution around `basename` is executed by the shell *before* it even starts running `find` (as a step in evaluating what the arguments to `find` should be).

Whenever you need to run anything other than a simple utility with optional arguments for a pathname found by `find`, for example if you need to do any piping, redirections or expansions (as in your question), you will need to employ a shell to do those things:

```bsh
find . -type f -name '*.jpg' \
    -exec sh -c 'img2pdf --output "$(basename "$1" .jpg).pdf" "$1"' sh {} \;
```

Or, more efficiently (each call to `sh -c` would handle a batch of found pathnames),

```bsh
find . -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        img2pdf --output "$(basename "$pathname" .jpg).pdf" "$pathname"
    done' sh {} +
```

Or, with `zsh`,

```bsh
for pathname in ./**/*.jpg(.DN); do
    img2pdf --output $pathname:t:r.png $pathname
done
```

This uses the globbing qualifier `.DN` to only match regular files (`.`), to allow matching of hidden names (`D`), and to remove the pattern if no matches are found (`N`).  It then uses the `:t` modifier to extract the "tail" (filename component) of `$pathname`, `:r` to extract the "root" (no filename suffix) of the resulting base name, and then adds `.png` to the end.

Note that all of the above variations would *write the output to the current directory*, regardless of where the JPEG file was found.  If all your JPEG files are in the current directory, there is absolutely no need to use `find`, and you could use a simple loop over the expansion of the `*.jpg` globbing pattern:

```bsh
for pathname in ./*.jpg; do
    img2pdf --output "${pathname%.jpg}.png" "$pathname"
done
```

The parameter substitution `${pathname%.jpg}` removes `.jpg` from the end of the value of `$pathname`.  You may possibly want to use this substitution *in place of* `basename` if you want to write the output to the original directories where the JPEG files were found, in the case that you use `find` over multiple directories, e.g., something like

```bsh
find . -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec sh -c '
    for pathname do
        img2pdf --output "${pathname%.jpg}.pdf" "$pathname"
    done' sh {} +
```

See also:

- [Understanding the -exec option of `find`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/389705)

Comment: Great and thorough answer. Thanks !

Comment: To write the output to the original directories where the JPEG files were found, the `for` loop is not necessary :
`find . -type f -name '*.jpg' -exec sh -c 'img2pdf --output "${1%.jpg}.pdf" "$1"' sh {} \;`

Comment: @ChennyStar No, the `for` loop is not _necessary_, but it make it _much_ more efficient as only a single shell is spawned for many found images.  Without the loop, you run not only `img2pdf` for each found file, but also `sh -c`, which makes it slower. This would be significant if you have many images.

Comment: OK, understood ! Thanks !

Comment: While I agree in theory, in practice the spawning of a shell for each file doesn't seem to have that *much* of an impact. I ran `img2pdf` on each `.jpg` file found in `/usr` (890 in my cases, I made a copy of `/usr` in `/tmp` for these tests). Roughly 4'58" in both cases (with or without a `for` loop). You can try yourself (make a copy of `/usr` to `/tmp` first) : `time sudo find /tmp/usr -name '*.jpg' -exec sh -c 'img2pdf --output "${1%.jpg}.pdf" "$1"' sh {} \;` vs `time sudo find /tmp/usr -name '*.jpg' -exec sh -c 'for f do img2pdf --output "${f%.jpg}.pdf" "$f"; done' sh {} \+`

Comment: @ChennyStar I'm wondering what you have against the loop.  Here's another example: Try `time find / -type f -exec sh -c 'echo .' \; 2>/dev/null | wc -l` to count all files on the system that your user can see, in a very inefficient way (starts `sh` for every file).  Then try with `time find / -type f -exec sh -c 'for p do echo .; done' sh {} + 2>/dev/null | wc -l`.  It obviously depends on what you're doing an on how many files you're doing it, but you will always find that spawning as few processes as possible will be faster.

Comment: Thanks. I have nothing against the loop, I was just surprised to find the same result with and without the loop, I expected better performances with the loop. But indeed I tested your examples and the difference is huge (almost 6 minutes vs 7 seconds with the loop, for around 300.000 files). I think in my examples with `img2pdf` the results were the same because it was only 890 files, and `im2pdf` itself takes about 400ms per file, so the impact of the spawning was very low. Anyway, thanks again, I understood a few things thanks to your answer.

Comment: @ChennyStar Yeah, the overhead of starting and running `img2pdf` drowned out the time used for starting `sh`.

Answer (score 1):

From a pragmatic point of view, once you have reached the state you describe at the end of your question:

```
./CamScanner 01-10-2022 14.56.jpg.pdf
./CamScanner 01-10-2022 14.55.jpg.pdf
./CamScanner 01-10-2022 14.54.jpg.pdf
```

You have the option of using `rename` to get the final file names you want:

```
~ rename 's/jpg.pdf/pdf/'
```

Answer (score 0):

@Ulrich Schwarz's comment is apt.  To bring it full circle, let's assume that you don't have any filenames with quotes or single-quotes in them.

Adapt your `find` syntax to simply output the basename sans the .jpg, and then use `awk` perhaps, to reconstruct the `img2pdf` syntax utilizing the `.jpg` and `.pdf` extensions where appropriate:

This `find` command will output the bare basename:

```
$ find . -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec basename {} .jpg \;
CamScanner 01-10-2022 14.56
CamScanner 01-10-2022 14.55
CamScanner 01-10-2022 14.54
```

Now pass those basenames to `awk` and let awk construct the correct syntax for `img2pdf`:

```
$  find . -type f -name "*.jpg" -exec basename {} .jpg \; | \
    awk '{print "cp -vp '\''" $0 ".jpg'\'' --output '\''" $0 ".pdf'\''"}'
img2pdf 'CamScanner 01-10-2022 14.56.jpg' --output 'CamScanner 01-10-2022 14.56.pdf'
img2pdf 'CamScanner 01-10-2022 14.55.jpg' --output 'CamScanner 01-10-2022 14.55.pdf'
img2pdf 'CamScanner 01-10-2022 14.54.jpg' --output 'CamScanner 01-10-2022 14.54.pdf'
```

If that syntax looks okay, then pipe it to your favorite shell.

Comment: Double quotes in filenames wouldn't be a problem but newline characters or leading dashes would be. With some shells, backslash or exclamation marks would be. With `yash`, so would sequences of bytes not forming valid characters in the locale.