# Why doesn't realpath --relative-to work in a command substitution?

Tags: find, command-substitution

```
user@debian:~/test/B$ find ..
..
../A
../A/x
../A/y
../A/z
../B
user@debian:~/test/B$ find ../A -type f -print0 |xargs -0 -i% realpath --relative-to=../A %
x
y
z
user@debian:~/test/B$ # But
user@debian:~/test/B$ find ../A -type f -print0 |xargs -0 -i% echo $(realpath --relative-to=../A %)
../B/../A/x
../B/../A/y
../B/../A/z
```

Muru suggested that the answers to the question "[find -exec command options with basename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/687271/find-exec-command-options-with-basename)" might  answer this question, but I'm not using `find` with `-exec`.

I don't understand muru's  explanation "the command substitution around `realpath` is executed by the shell before it even starts running `xargs` (as a step in evaluating what the arguments to `xargs` should be)":

- How can `realpath --relative-to=../A` be evaluated before the call to `xargs`?
- Even if it is evaluated, what does it evaluate to, and why does that lead to a different output?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [find -exec command options with basename](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/687271/find-exec-command-options-with-basename)

Comment: @muru This is somewhat helpful but the [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/687273/55900) mentions "the command substitution around `basename` is executed by the shell *before* it even starts running `find` (as a step in evaluating what the arguments to `find` should be). I'm not exactly sure whether that applies to my case as I'm not using `find` with `-exec`.

Comment: In this scenario, `find ... -print0 | xargs -0` is just a long-winded way of doing `find ... -exec`.

Comment: @muru Functionally equivalent maybe, but what I'm after is an explanation of why the substitution doesn't work that way. What is different between my two examples?

Comment: Exactly the bit you quoted, _mutatis mutandis_: "the command substitution around `realpath` is executed by the shell _before_ it even starts running `xargs` (as a step in evaluating what the arguments to `xargs` should be)".

Comment: "How can realpath --relative-to=../A be evaluated before the call to xargs?" Why can't it be? Run `realpath --relative-to=../A %` in your shell to see what it is evaluated to.

Comment: @muru OK, then I don't understand how `%` can get substituted for the `xargs` input from the output of `find`.

Comment: It is not being substituted, since `xargs` is not there to substitute it. `%` is only special to `xargs`, the shell will just use `%` as it is.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/149159/discussion-between-friendfx-and-muru).

Answer (score 0):

#### Explanation

Thanks to @muru for walking me through finding my own answer.  Here is what is happening:

When the shell sees the command line

```
find ../A -type f -print0 |xargs -0 -i% echo $(realpath --relative-to=../A %)
```

it first evaluates the command subsitution

```
realpath --relative-to=../A %
```

which evaluates to `../B/%`.

Therefore the effective command that is being executed when `find` starts is this:

```
find ../A -type f -print0 |xargs -0 -i% echo ../B/%
```

...which doesn't call `realpath` at all, but simply appends the `find` output to `../B/`.

#### Workaround

Don't use a command substitution there, use plain `realpath` to do its work before doing whatever you wanted to do in the first place (not very much in this example, but this could obviously be extended):

```
find ../A -type f -print0 |xargs -0 -i% realpath -z --relative-to=../A % |xargs -0 -i% echo %
```